# SQLite json_array_length

Tags: arrays, json, sqlite, case

Trying to run a query on a column containing JSON data.

When I run the following:

```
SELECT json_array_length(threads.participants)
FROM threads
```

I get results of 2 and 119 (2 json arrays in most records, 119 in just one of them).

I tried another query using a CASE statement as the following:

```
SELECT
  CASE threads.participants
    WHEN json_array_length(threads.participants) = 2 THEN "2 Participants"
    ELSE "More than 2 Participants" 
  END AS "Number of Participants"
FROM threads
```

I get all NULL results for the second query. I expected to see the same number of results as the first query, just changed to "2 Participants" and "More than 2 Participants". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use in the `CASE` expression is wrong.
Try this:

```
SELECT CASE json_array_length(participants) 
         WHEN 2 THEN '2 Participants' 
         ELSE 'More than 2 Participants' 
       END AS "Number of Participants" 
FROM threads
```

Just to be on the safe side, you should include all possible cases (even if they don't currently exist):

```
SELECT CASE json_array_length(participants) 
         WHEN 0 THEN 'No Participants' 
         WHEN 1 THEN '1 Participant' 
         WHEN 2 THEN '2 Participants' 
         ELSE 'More than 2 Participants' 
       END AS "Number of Participants" 
FROM threads
```